# Deploying with Docker into production: Zero downtime

Tags: php, deployment, docker, continuous-integration, ansible

Im failing to see how it is possible to achieve zero-downtime deployments with Docker.

Let's say I have a PHP container running *MyWebApp* being served by an *Nginx* container on the same server. I then change some code, as Docker containers are immutable I have to build/deploy the *MyWebApp* container again with the code changes. During the time it takes to do this *MyWebApp* is down for the count...

Previously I would use Ansible or similar to do deploy my code, then symlink the new release directory to the web dir... zero-downtime!

**Is it possible to achieve zero downtime deployments with Docker and a single server app?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do some kind of [blue-green deployment](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html) with your containers, using nginx `upstreams`'s:

```
upstream containers {
  server 127.0.0.1:9990;  # blue
  server 127.0.0.1:9991;  # green
}

location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_pass containers;
  ...
}
```

Then, when deploying your containers, you'll have to alternate between port mappings:

```
# assuming php-fpm runs on port 9000 inside the container
# current state: green container running, need to deploy blue
# get last app version
docker pull my_app
# remove previous container (was already stopped)
docker rm blue
# start new container
docker run -p 9990:9000 --name blue my_app
# at this point both containers are running and serve traffic
docker stop green
# nginx will detect failure on green and stop trying to send traffic to it
```

To deploy green, change color name and port mapping.

You might want to fiddle with [upstream server entry parameters](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#server) to make the switchover faster, or use `haproxy` in your stack and manually (or automatically via management socket) manage backends.

If things go wrong, just `docker start the_previous_color` and `docker stop the_latest_color`.

Since you use Ansible, you could use it to orchestrate this process, and even add smoke tests to the mix so a rollback is automatically triggered if something goes wrong.

Comment: Awesome that was close to my original idea. Although in the end I went with something similar, with an Nginx load balancer sitting between two servers running docker. That way I also get hardware failover and datacentre failover. THANK YOU.