# Docker services route network before task is actually up - zero downtime

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm currently running *Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40* on multiple nodes. My setup is a nginx service and multiple java restful API services running in a wildfly cluster.
For my API services I've configured a simple healthcheck to determine whether my API task is actually up:

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=5m --timeout=3s \
  --retries=2 --start-period=1m  \
  CMD curl -f http://localhost:8080/api/healthcheck || exit 1
```

But even with the use of [HealthCheck](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) my nginx sometimes gets and error - caused by the fact that the API is still not fully up - can't serve rest requests.

The only solution, that I managed to get working so far is increasing the *--start-period* by hand to a lot longer periods.

How does the docker service [load balancer](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/getting-started/deploy-app/9_load-balance_the_service/) decide, when to start routing requests to the new service?

Is setting a higher time with the *--start-period* currently the only way to prevent load balancer from redirecting traffic to a task that is not ready for traffic or am I missing something?

I've seen the "blue-green" deployment answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34106964/deploying-with-docker-into-production-zero-downtime) where you can manage zero downtime, but I'm still hoping this could be done with the use of docker services.

Comment: I'm guessing that your healthcheck http://localhost:8080/api/healthchck is not giving the responses you expect. If it's responding at all then it seems logical that your api is up and running, and docker will then start routing requests to it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think the problem is not in my healthcheck, but that docker service load balancer marks task as running and starts redirecting traffic before that task passes my healthcheck and is considered "healthy". I might be wrong and I am guessing that's the issue.

Comment: Good guess, but essentially wrong (unless there's a weird bug that nobody has noticed before). Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43340147/should-swarm-loadbalancing-perform-healthchecks-on-its-nodes

Comment: Thank you, will go trough that and the moby issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routing mesh will start routing traffic on the "first successful healthcheck", even if future ones fail.

Whatever you put in the HEALTHCHECK command it needs to only start returning "exit 0" when things are truly ready. If it returns a good result too early, then that's not a good healthcheck command.

The `--start-period` only tells swarm when to kill the task if it's yet to receive a successful healthcheck in that time, but it won't cause green healthchecks to be ignored during the start period.

Comment: So if my healthcheck is successful "too soon", that would explain the issue. I will check if that is so, but I am unsure how to test it.
If I want to delay the "first healthchek" how would I do that? Set up the `--interval` to a higher value? Does docker healthcheck on container start runs every `--interval`, starting at `--start-period` or when does it start? According to your answer the `--start-period` would only not count the failed attempts. Thanks!

Comment: I've configured my healthcheck to be more precise and for now it seems to be working as expected.
Marking this answer as correct, because of the explanation of the routing mesh and start-period. Thanks again!